# Built in Tablet Chargers in the Van--Voltage regulation heat dissipation a problem?

Tags: voltage-regulator, heatsink, power-dissipation

Ok, for fun and enjoyment I have decided to build in chargers in a number of positions on the "Mom Van."  But either I can't do math, or I am missing something.  I want tablet style chargers capable of 2 amps, but when I do the math--basically I'm going to set the car on fire.  I chose:

A to-220 5v rated to 2 amps
https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/389/l78s-974158.pdf

And there will be heat sinks--currently thinking of these:
https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/303/sink_csm-1265487.pdf

My problem is that with a voltage drop from 14.4 to 5 and at 2 amps I get (9.4v)(2A)=18.8Watts.  Take the 50C/W rating from the data sheet and I get a temperature rise to air of: 50C(9.4)=940C.

I could buy these chargers for a couple bucks (but this is more fun, and I want them built in seamlessly)

I must be missing something? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: And now you know why no one uses linear regulators for this.

Comment: See Figure 27 .

Answer (score 2):

Your math is correct. Although 940 C is a bit high, they usually limit around 120 C. You will still create a nice heater using linear regulators. Which is why people don't use them for a big drop in voltage.

Today we use [switching power supplies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switched-mode_power_supply).

And there are [little modules](https://www.recom-power.com/pdf/Innoline/R-78Bxx-2.0.pdf) as easy as those linear regulators.
[image: R-78B-2.0]

They are more expensive directly compared to a single linear regulator. But it will earn itself back if you look at the whole project, and wasted energy during usage.

Comment: Thanks! Totally willing to spend a few dollars to do it right, my ignorance was blocking me. I'll go find some switching power supplies.